# Saving incorrect col separator in csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Basically I'm reading a large csv file, and it has some mistakes. Few of the columns are separated by `dot` instead of `comma`. Does anyone know of a way to still run those lines ? 
example mistake on line two between "test". "test":

```
CSV.foreach("#{Rails.root}/tmp/test.csv") do |row|

puts  "Mrs","test","test","U26453"
puts  "Mr","test"."test@emai.com","U50406"  - CSV::MalformedCSVError: Missing or stray quote in line 2
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using?

Comment: this is just a short example of what each row will print out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a small regex, which will split by different characters:

`split(/[,.]/)`

```
v = '"Mrs","test","test","U26453"'
v.split(/[,.]/)
=> ["\"Mrs\"", "\"test\"", "\"test\"", "\"U26453\""]
```

UPDATE:

As @gerep noticed, the above will not split correctly when `.` or `,` are inside of the substring. As a solution:

```
split(/"[,.]"/)
```

Comment: It won't work in case there is a dot or comma in any element, like: `"Mr","test.something"."test","U50406"`

Comment: i need to keep commas and clean text, and the text have some dots in there as well.